# Loop over function args on the stack, using a register as an index for ESP?

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

Just a short question.
Anyone knows if there is any way that I can do this in assembly?

```
movl $4, %ebx
movl (%ebx)(%esp), %eax
```

what I'm trying to do is basically create a loop that extras the next argument(fixed size) from the stack.

example:

```
int foo( int x, int y, int z, int a){
    if(x == y){
         x = z;
       if(y == z){
            printf("%d", a);
      }
    }
}
```

instead of immediately loading x, y, z and a into the register, can I load a into the register only when I'm sure that the first 2 conditions are true.

p/s: wrote the code on the fly, doesn't really do anything useful.

Comment: What do you mean by `(%ebx)(%esp)`?

Comment: `movl $4, %ebx` does not look Intel to me. Looks AT&T. What's your compiler?

Comment: @m0skit0 Perhaps, `($esp,$ebx)` or the other way around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want this

```
movl $1, %ebx
movl (%esp,%ebx,$4), $eax
```

incrementing %ebx by one each time to get to the next argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
movl (%esp,%ebx),%eax
```

is accepted by my compiler.

The syntax is

```
mov'suffix' (offset,base[,scale]),target
```

with the scale in brackets because it is optional